# How to disable XML comment warning in workflow auto-generated code in .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: c#-4.0, compiler-construction, workflow-foundation-4

We've had this issue of getting compiler warnings for XML comments missing on code that Workflow Foundation generates during compilation.  Because we treat all warnings as errors, our compilation fails.

Yes, we could simply instruct the compiler to ignore specific warnings and thus not fail compilation anymore, but that would mean that any code in the project would be exempted from having XML comments.

So the question is: is there a way of disabling the warning on missing XML comments just for workflow foundation-generated code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Quoc Lam's blog (http://lvquoc.blogspot.com/2010/11/disable-xml-comment-warning-in-workflow.html), the following can be done:

<Target Name="XamlGeneratedCodeWarningRemoved" AfterTargets="XamlMarkupCompilePass1">
    <Exec Command="for %%f in (@(XamlGeneratedCodeFiles)) do echo #pragma warning disable > %%f.temp" />
    <Exec Command="for %%f in (@(XamlGeneratedCodeFiles)) do type %%f >> %%f.temp" />
    <Exec Command="for %%f in (@(XamlGeneratedCodeFiles)) do copy /y %%f.temp %%f" />
    <Message Text="XamlGeneratedCodeWarningRemoved: @(XamlGeneratedCodeFiles)" />
  </Target>

This causes a "#pragma warning disable" to be inserted into the generated code.  See the blog entry for detailed information on how this works.